# Is it be a bad idea to use JNI to leverage JDBC in C/C++?

Tags: java, c++, jdbc, java-native-interface, odbc

I am thinking about starting a project that will communicate to multiple DBMS's. Although unavailable directly from C/C++, JDBC remains attractive for the following reasons:

1. My software shall be portable between Windows/OSX/Linux. Managing ODBC on each of these platforms on multiple architectures seems very cumbersome as far as I've looked.
2. I was planning on distributing the JDBC libraries with my application. This seems like a better option that trying to distributing each ODBC driver for the multiple environments.
3. I am far more familiar with JDBC than with ODBC.
4. It seems as though JDBC may be better supported in some cases.

I've all but convinced myself this is the way to go. However, I don't know if my inexperience with ODBC and JNI are leading me to make naive conclusions.

Please advise.

Comment: So you will essentially be embedding the JVM in your native code app? Given what are trying to achieve I think that's your best bet. As long as you get pure Java JDBC drivers you should be good to go. The only way ODBC would work is if you can get UnixODBC to work - you might need to buy driver packages depending on the DBMS involved. Too much pain for little / no gain if you ask me.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't involve JNI/Java just for the sake of ODBC.  On Windows, just use the native ODBC API. On *nix, unixodbc works well. Also, there are 3rd party vendors such as Progress (DataDirect).

The only gotcha I've seen with unixodbc (and it's not really a unixodbc problem) is with mixing Sybase ASE & Sybase IQ. The Sybase provided drivers for the two DBMS are built differently, making them incompatible at runtime for x64 systems (one is built expecting 32-bit types, the other 64-bit types, and unixodbc must be built accordingly to match the driver needed, and you cannot use both at the same time).

I'd also recommend using an abstraction layer, such as [odbc++](http://libodbcxx.sourceforge.net/) (sadly, seems to not be actively maintained - and note the latest odbc++ has 64-bit compatibility issues out of the box), or [OTL](http://otl.sourceforge.net/) (which is actively being maintained).